# Why did the Colombian deal go wrong in Scarface?

Tags: plot-explanation, scarface

In *Scarface*, Tony and his crew are sent by Omar on a deal with Colombians. That deal didn't end well for both Hector and Tony's crews. But I don't understand what went wrong.

With Omar's connections and Frank's money, Tony is supposed to buy Hector's cocaine. Tony doesn't seem to have funny businesses in mind, just wants to make the deal. Hower, the Colombians quickly freak out. I don't understand why Hector suspects something on Tony. As a professional drug dealer, Hector knows that no one would simply come waving the money before checking if the deal is legit, but he seems to blame Tony for his cautiousness.

Also, the Colombians had the drug, so they intend to make the deal, so why did it end that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a chainsaw in the briefcase is not a sign of willingness to do the deal. They wanted to kill them and keep the money and drugs. They did bring drugs with them because if they didn't showed them, Tony (or whoever would attend the deal) would kill them on the spot.

Hector killed Angel to force Tony to give him the money. They were hoping the Lopez people will have money on them. But as Tony didn't like/trust Columbians he made Chi-chi and Many wait the 15 minutes. Remember that the Tony was put to the deal in last minute so maybe Hector was expecting someone else.

Omar was a police informant so we know he wasn't loyal to Frank. Then, he offered Tony the marijuana deal which he refused and in the anger he offers him deal with Colombians.

So he either knew it would be a trap and wanted to get ride of Tony and Many. Or he had a deal with Colombians. Maybe that's why Sosa decide to kill him. Because they made a deal before that didn't work out and Tony was better tool to destroy Lopez.

Comment: But what was the point of killing them they didn't even hand the money... What's the point of faking a deal just to kill random Cuban guys (in Hector's mind)?

Comment: Hector killed Angel to force Tony to give him the money. They were hoping the Lopez people will have money on them. But as Tony didn't like/trust Columbians he made Chi-chi and Many wait the 15 minutes. Remember that the Tony was put to the deal in last minute so maybe Hector was expecting someone else.

Comment: But the deal connection was given by Omar, so it should be a fair deal I guess... Why would the Colombians want to screw Frank over? And I think it would be better to write the answer in the answer section, not it comments ;-)

Comment: I edited and expanded the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the bounty, it failed somehow...

Answer (score 3):

The movie doesn't specify, but I always assumed that Omar wasn't interested in dealing with the Colombians himself. Maybe he didn't know enough about the people, or considered them shady, or maybe he straight-up knew they would ambush whoever came knocking -- the back story is not provided.

But it is clear that **when taco-shop Tony started demanding a bigger piece of the action (and being a jerk about it), Omar offered the high-risk deal to Tony (largely out of spite).** It was that moment in the parking lot when Omar had just been enraged by Tony *to the point of pulling a gun on him.*

Omar only put the gun away when when his friend begged him to and suggested the deal as an alternative. Sure enough, it turned out **the Colombians never intended to sell their cocaine -- only to use it as a lure to draw big money that they could steal.**

Omar was right to have not been interested. He might have even been trying to send Tony to his death. But Tony turned the tables by coming out alive, with the *llello*, a result that earned him personal access to Frank Lopez.

Answer (score 0):

Omar was a snake from the beginning, the Columbians knew Tony was coming, they already was pack with heat. The little whisper Omar's friend gave was a spark Tony should have paid attention to.

Answer (score -1):

I don't mean to blunt but the answer is simple: they were just trying to rob Tony. I don't think Omar knew, I think he didn't, as Tony didn't either, trust the Colombians, and they both were right not to.

Had Omar showed up, he would've gotten the same fate. The Colombians were gonna rob them, period. In the drug game, that is what happens, some deals​ go through, some don't. And some get robbed... It's called "getting 
ganked".